# Diagonalisability with $\lambda = 2,x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have a $2 \times 2$ matrix, $Y(x)$, with $2$ eigenvalues: $\lambda = 2,x$ where $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Now $Y(x)$ is only diagonalisable if $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are distinct. Are $2,x$ distinct? I think not due to the fact that $x$ can take value $2$, is this intuition correct?

Would $Y(x)$ be diagonalisable $\forall x \ne 2$?

Comment: Actually, having two different eigenvalues is sufficient but not necessary for diagonalizability of a $2\times 2$ matrix. You need an eigenspace of dimension $2$ as a sufficient condition. So, yes, any $2\times 2$ matrix with two eigenvalues is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement that $Y(x)$ is **only** diagonalisable if $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are distinct is not correct.

If the eigenvalues are distinct then the matrix is diagonalisable.  So, if $x\ne2$ then $Y$ is diagonalisable.

But if there are repeated eigenvalues the matrix **may** still be diagonalisable.  For example, if
$$Y=\pmatrix{2&0\cr0&2\cr}$$
then the eigenvalues are $2,2$ and $Y$ is diagonalisable.  On the other hand, if say
$$Y=\pmatrix{2&1\cr0&2\cr}$$
then the eigenvalues are $2,2$ and $Y$ is not diagonalisable.

Comment: Very good answer, thank you for that extended answer and neat formatting!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, having two different eigenvalues is sufficient but not necessary for diagonalizability of a $2\times 2$ matrix. You need an eigenspace of dimension $2$ as a sufficient condition. So, yes, any $2\times 2$ matrix with two eigenvalues is diagonalizable. To illustrate this point  while being lazy, let me ripoff David's example:

$$Y=\pmatrix{2&0\cr0&2\cr}$$

You can see that the eigenspace is the whole of $\mathbb R^2$, since for any vector $(x,y)^T$ we have $$Y(x,y)^T=(2x,2y)=2(x,y) $$

So the eigenspace has dimension 2 (which happens to be the full dimension of the space).

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know how to enter matrices.

Comment: begin{align}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4\\
end{align}

With \ in front of begin and end. \\ starts a new line and & puts a space in. Outside of align, throw in \right( and then after align \left).

$\left(\begin{align}
1 & 2\\
3 & 4\\
\end{align}\right)$

Comment: @DisplayName: Thanks.